# Toroid with 8 leads

Tags: transformer

I was salvaging parts from a broken computer power supply and I noticed the largest toroid had 8 leads. How do I use such a thing? There seem to be 4 inputs and 4 outputs such that there is a pair inputs and a pair of outputs on either side of the device.

I could guess that each input output pair winds in a different direction, but I thought it best ask before I do anything with it.

Comment: FAr too little information provided. Photo a good idea. Description of power supply functionality useful. Where it connects (input side or output side.
IF on output side it is probably a coupled filtering inductor. If on primary side or between in and out it's almost certainly the  main converter transformer.

Comment: I did not realize there were so many types of 8 lead toriods. Sorry, but I do not really have much more info on it. I really only have the components of the power supply at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have a quadfilar toroid if it looks similar to this:

[image: quadfilar toroid]

Bifilar toroids are wound with 2 parallel insulated wires, trifilar 3 parallel wires.

Comment: The wires are not that symmetric looking, but the leads are right (four on either side.) I suppose that seems like a reasonable enough guess.